# add legend in a histogram (lattice)

Tags: r, histogram, legend, lattice

I am new to R programming and I would like to make a histogram about sex and the correspondent jobs.

The problem I have is that I can't add a legend in the diagram.

Also, I would like on the top of every bar to add the frequency number.

Could you help me please ?

```
library(lattice)
histogram(~ job | sex, col=rainbow(7), main="", xlab = "", ylab="(%)")
```

P.S. I am trying with legend function but I get this error:

> Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex) : 
>     plot.new has not been called yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you have been reading intro material that taught you to use `attach`. Try to unlearn that. It's a bad habit if you want to use lattice. (And a generally bad habit all around for writing code.)  Assuming you have these two variables in a dataframe, `dfrm` in long format, then try this:

```
library(lattice)
histogram(~ job | sex, data=dfrm, auto.key=TRUE, 
                      col=rainbow(7),  main="", xlab = "", ylab="(%)")
```

The `legend` function will not mix well with lattice, since it is base graphics. You could try, but the coordinate system for placement is very different.

I tested a variant of the above with the `singer` dataset and it did not succeed. This example works after adding a `Freq` column to the singer dataset:

```
singer$Freq <- ave(singer$height, singer$voice.part, FUN=length)
barchart(Freq ~ height, groups = voice.part,
        data = singer, 
        stack = TRUE, horizontal=FALSE,
   par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col=rainbow(8))), 
   auto.key=list(x = .6, y = .7, corner = c(0, 0)))
```

Comment: @user49766 If it's what you wanted, then you should "accept" or "check" the answer.